# Fixing warnings of non-conformance to "Sendable" for ImageResource in Swift 5.10

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, concurrency

I have a file with some constants that maps enums to associated `ImageResource` for simplified usage in other places. Sample is below

```
  static let imagePreviews: [MyEnum: ImageResource] = [
    .Enum1: .imageResource1,
    .Enum1: .imageResource2,
    ...
  ]
```

After upgrading to latest XCode that uses Swift 5.10 following warning is shown around code block above and judging by other similar warnings, common pattern is usage of `ImageResource`

> Static property 'activityBlockImagePreviews' is not concurrency-safe
> because it is not either conforming to 'Sendable' or isolated to a
> global actor; this is an error in Swift 6

Comment: It should be possible to add a minimal, buildable example which demonstrates the issue. You might want to read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15_3-release-notes , specifically the sections regarding the new concurrency checking rules added in the version of the compiler. Possibly related: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0412-strict-concurrency-for-global-variables.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have a `static` (or a global) that represents an unsynchronized, shared mutable state. If this was your own type, you could make it `Sendable`. (See WWDC 2022 video [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/).)

But I presume you are using the framework’s [`ImageResource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/developertoolssupport/imageresource/) type, which is not `Sendable`. So, you can get around this lack of sendability of the underlying type by synchronizing your interaction with your properties. You can achieve this with a global actor. E.g., if you wanted to isolate it to the main actor:

```swift
@MainActor
extension ImageResource {
    static let imageResource1 = ImageResource(name: "foo", bundle: .main)
    static let imageResource2 = ImageResource(name: "bar", bundle: .main)
}
```

And then:

```swift
@MainActor
static let imagePreviews: [MyEnum: ImageResource] = [
    .foo: .imageResource1,
    .bar: .imageResource2
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use global actors to control access

```
@MainActor static let imagePreviews: [MyEnum: ImageResource] = [
    .Enum1: .imageResource1,
    .Enum1: .imageResource2,
    ...
  ]
```

This will add a whole other layer of complexity to the app because of the class, struct, method that calls isn’t already on the same actor you will have to await.

```
await imagePreviews
```

You don’t have to use `MainActor` you can create your own.